# How to remove active notifications from the status bar programmatically in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, notifications

I want to remove all the active notifications from the device, in android there is a way to do this and it is by using this: `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancelAll()`

I want to know flutter's alternative for this, I have tried finding one with the plugin flutter_local_notifications but there isn't.

Comment: Of course, it works. But what are the problems you are facing? Have you tried the example `flutter_local_notifications` package provide?

Comment: You can use `await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();`

Comment: @DarShan I think the `.cancelAll()` method is to cancel only my apps' notifications, not other active ones as well

Comment: You won’t be able to to do this on iOS. For android communication via dart, use a MethodChannel.

Comment: I don't need to do it on iOS, but how do I use a MethodChannel for my problem?

Comment: @ShlokJain I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?